# SVN and odd file

Tags: permissions, svn, file-permissions, tortoise-svn, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I just did an SVN update and found a weird .pptx file that I cannot open. (When I double-click, it does not open.) Then when I right click on the file, it shows only a small amount of options I can do
[image]

rather than the other normal .pptx files I can open that when I right click, it shows:
[image]

How can I get around this? Or rather, what is wrong with this file? I think it has something to do with file permissions but other than that have no clue. Any ideas are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is a .pptx (Microsoft Office Power Point 2007) file right?
Can you use a hexviewer to check the file header? Maybe it's corrupt due to an incomplete transfer.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the filename? _ie_ could it possibly contain strange characters?  What do you see if you do `dir *.pptx` in that directory from the command prompt?  The file is already under revision control, right?  Can you delete the file and update again?

Comment: It's also possible that the file was somehow created with no permissions...  You could try adding the 'Take Ownership' option to your context menu: [link](http://www.techspot.com/guides/253-take-ownership-windows-files/)

Comment: @paddy: there is no strange character in the filename. I do see the file when I do `dir *.pptx` in that directory. Strange thing is that I cannot delete the file inside that folder, but I can delete the whole folder. However when I update again, the bizarre behavior seems to be still present. I also don't have the 'Take Ownership' option since I am using Windows XP. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherWilson Yes, this is a Microsoft Office Power Point 2007 file. Not quite sure how to use a hex editor to check to see that the file header is correct, but I deleted it and reupdated, but the same thing happens. This doesn't seem to be a problem for others getting the same file in the svn repository. :(...

Comment: Sorry, been away for a while.  Did you solve this?  What happens if you zip the directory and unzip to a new location?  If the problem persists when doing that, why don't you send me the zip?  I'm curious.  Presumably there's a contact feature via superuser.com =)  What happens if you go into that directory in the command prompt and type `attrib`?

Comment: Hi paddy, yes I solved it. Turns out it was a filename limit of svn. Checking out just that intermediate folder and its contents, I was able to open the .pptx. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of others who may be having the same problem, it seems like SVN has a directory/filename character limit. If I checked out the intermediate folder and its contents, I was able to open the files. To fix this problem, do a `Rename...` to the long folder names...